# Push and pull data into ui.bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, ui.bootstrap

I have set up a plunkr here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/NdHqQJ?p=preview

I'm trying to push and pull the form data into the modal window when you click on the task. I have read that you can do this with the "resolve" property (seen below) of the modal but I have been unable to get it to actually work. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'editTask.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: size,
  scope: $scope,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});
```

Please let me know if you need more details!

Comment: Too much code. To answer your question it would be enough to set up much simpler demo.

Comment: You can also achieve it using services and allow the main controller and modal controller to pass data between each other using the service.

Comment: Okay, now what is what doe you want to pass to/from this simplified modal in your demo?

Comment: @dfsq Just the subject is fine. I just need an example. I put the form control into the modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use resolve (you can) the nit will be like this for example:

```
$scope.open = function(size, task) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'editTask.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            task: function() {
                return task
            }
        }
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
<a ng-click="open('lg', noStoneTask)" style="cursor:pointer" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Open Task">{{noStoneTask.taskSubject}}</a>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/NA71479d04Yw7hh2Twx8?p=preview

Comment: Awesome, I modified your plunk slightly to include an input. How do I pass the value of the input back to the main page? http://plnkr.co/edit/V91Zm3LJeoG0Y1alBEqx?p=preview

Comment: You can bind input to the copy of the passed task object and update changed properties of the original task object if Ok was pressed. http://plnkr.co/edit/iBqzbnx6ECdO0hJzFeY5?p=info

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the scope you want to resolve (pass to the modal) in the resolve. and resolve it in the modal controller.

Is this what you want to achieve?
http://plnkr.co/edit/Q0G79C?p=preview

I modified the modal to pass the noStoneTasks scope to the modal

```
//modal
$scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'editTask.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            noStoneTasks: function () {
                return $scope.noStoneTasks;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

I also modify the scope when the user click ok.

```
uxModule.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, noStoneTasks) {
    $scope.ok = function () {
        noStoneTasks[0].actHours++;
        $modalInstance.close('save');
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```